# How can I convert a text file stored in HDFS containing Rows into a Dataframe in Pyspark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs, apache-spark-sql

I am working with Pyspark and recentrly stored a dataframe as textfile in HDFS like this:

```
df.rdd.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile(path)
```

The file was succesfully created but the format of the content is as follows:

```
Row(APP_PRESS=0.8322056773315432, LINE_PRESS=0.0, POSITION=324.17885120541024, SH_SP=-1.610030115550595, TEMP=24.300001144400007, TRIGGER=4.0869775365401934e-19, V_IND=98.36323547359974)
Row(APP_PRESS=0.8025359920151738, LINE_PRESS=0.0, POSITION=324.12892475616513, SH_SP=1.8780468896210554, TEMP=24.300001144399893, TRIGGER=-1.7645281682240943e-19, V_IND=98.36323547359977)
...
```

Now, what I want to do is to load those data in a dataframe in Pyspark, just to get the same dataframe as the saved before ('df').

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
df=sc.textFile(...).toDF()
```

But you could avoid this step by amending your code above to:

```
df.rdd.repartition(1).toDF()
```

and then saving.

Comment: When I tried the option "df=sc.textFile(...).toDF()" I get the error message: TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'str'>

Comment: sorry, yes my mistake, that won't work as it is an rdd of strings. The easiest way is probably the second part I wrote-do you absolutely need to save as a text file?

Comment: Not really. If i execute "df.rdd.repartition(1).toDF()" how do I specify where to save the dataframe in HDFS?

Comment: the same way you do for the rdd, using something like `df.write.save(path)`

Comment: And to load the dataframe after saving which command must I use?

Comment: Thanks! Great answer!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped